# Add a new div once the height exceeds certain amount of pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to divide the pages that are going to be printed, so I decided to get the max amount of height pixels everytime that a div is added and then when it reaches, For example, between 700px and 720px, it'll add another header to it, which means that it's the second page that will print.

The problem is that the height of each div it's gonna be different like:

```
<div id="1"> <!-- example: height:40px--> </div>
<div id="2"> <!-- height:20px --> </div>
```

It's will be a undefined height that depends on the amount of text that will come from the Database.

I can't do onload on the body because the divs would be already loaded and onload doesn't work with divs.

I still can't figure out a way to do it, any ideas would be appreciated

I'm using Classic ASP with VBscript here(if it helps for something)

Thanks!

Comment: youd' be better off dumping all of your text into a single block, then use client-side code to tear apart that block into chunks and start adding chunks to divs until the divs' height exceeds 700px. you can't really do much on the server to figure out how big client-side text will be rendered. e.g. a vision impaired person in "large print" mode will have MUCH less text per div than a normal sighted person

Comment: Nice idea, I'll try to think in something with that.
I don't have many options since I don't know how bigger will be the text.
Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

'Determine the max numbers of characters you can fit into your `div`s, then from your page generation script split your content in multiple divs.
for exemple with PHP:

```
<?php
// Suppose the content is within the variable data and the max-length is 500 charcaters
$i = 1;
while ($data) {
    echo '<div id="' . $i++ .'">'. substr($data, 0, 500) . "</div>";
    $data = substr($data, 500);
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem there is like i'm going to have something like:
date - Description of the problem - person who wrote to us (just similar to a table)
Then it's not limited the number of characters in database, so limiting then would just cut of the bigger ones, something I may do is to search which has the bigger length and try to figure out some way to deduce the heights, but it's really risky I guess...